# How to set icon in gtk.AboutDialog on Windows?

Tags: python, pygtk, graphical-logo, about-box

I have an about dialog in my Python application and I want to set a custom icon for the dialog.

I looked at [`set_logo_icon_name()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkaboutdialog.html#method-gtkaboutdialog--set-logo-icon-name), but that doesn't accept an absolute path to an image.

What can I do to insert my custom icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_logo()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkaboutdialog.html#method-gtkaboutdialog--set-logo) instead. `set_logo_icon_name()` is for named (i.e., themed) icons. `set_logo()` takes a `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf` which you can create from an absolute image path with [`gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html#function-gdk--pixbuf-new-from-file).

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I missed that function.

Comment: Would you guys know how to do that (use a stock icon as GtkAboutDialog logo) now, with Gtk + 3?

Comment: All the links to documentation have rotted. ☹